# Application pool identity for web API and AD

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I would like my asp.net web API application to automatically create AD account in my domain.
Which application pool identity should I use? Or maybe I could programmatically use the identity of the IT person, who uses this web application? If yes, then how to do it?

Comment: Since an elevated account (domain administrator for example) is required "to automatically create AD account in my domain", you'd better create a separate application and run under such an account.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by automatically, but you need to make the user object by code. The Identity the app is running under needs to have the right to make user objects under a specified OU. The code creates user objects in this spesified OU.

If the app runs under "<app-user>", this credential should be given the right to create objects under the "target OU". As a short-time test, you can give the user "Domain Admin" rights.

You can also test if the correct permissions has been granted by starting Active Directory Users and Computer or running a powershell script, with these credentials.

You should NOT use the credentials of a real IT person.

The code you need to create a user object in Active Directory you can easily find here on Stackoverflow.